# How/where do I tell the compiler to use ecmascript 6

Tags: compiler-errors, ecmascript-6, google-tag-manager, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

#### What I am trying to accomplish:

- Use [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) to dynamically build `JSON-LD` script

#### Why:

- To create a `Rich Card` showcased in the `SERP`

---

#### Problem:

When trying to create a [User-Defined Variable](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106899?hl=en) as well as the script used by the [Tag](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en#whatIsATag) itself.  When utilizing the [Preview and Debug](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en) feature of GTM. I receive the following error:

> this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: let declaration. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features.

I understand... or at least I think I understand that I need to tell the compiler to

> Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT

But how do I accomplish this?

```js
<script>
(function(){
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @language_in=ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT;
// @language_out=ES5_STRICT;
 // ==/ClosureCompiler==

 "use strict";
  let data = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "MovingCompany",
  "name": "WDA Movers",
  "logo" : {
    "@type" : "ImageObject",
    "url" : "http://wda-moving.online/images/logo.jpg",
    "height" : 435,
    "width" : 361      
  },
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Eugene",
    "addressRegion": "OR",
    "postalCode": "97404",
    "streetAddress": "411 Heywood Avenue"
  },
  "openingHours": "Mo-Su 7:00-23:30",
  "priceRange": "$$$",
  "telephone": "(541) 255-9876",
  "url": "http://wda-moving.online",
  "sameAs" : [
    "https://www.facebook.com/wda.movers/",
    "https://plus.google.com/+WDAMoversEugene/about?gmbpt=true&hl=en"
  ],
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": {{YELP_rating}},
    "reviewCount": {{YELP_review_count}},
    "bestRating": "5",
    "worstRating": "1"
  },
  "review": {
"@type" : "Review",
"author" : {{YELP_reviews_user_name}},
"reviewBody" : {{YELP_reviews_excerpt}},
"reviewRating" : {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": {{YELP_reviews_rating}}
    }
   }
 }
 let richCard = document.createElement('script');
 richCard.type = "application/ld+json";
 richCard.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(richCard);
 })(document);
 </script>
```

As you can see I've tried adding the following to the script above:

```js
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @language_in=ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT;
// @language_out=ES5_STRICT;
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

"use strict";
```

This did not work... can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the [asset-pipeline plugin](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/asset-pipeline), you will find the following example for `build.gradle`:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    enableSourceMaps = true
    configOptions = [:]

    minifyOptions = [
        languageMode: 'ES5',
        targetLanguage: 'ES5', //Can go from ES6 to ES5 for those bleeding edgers
        optimizationLevel: 'SIMPLE',
        angularPass: true // Can use @ngInject annotation for Angular Apps
    ]
    // ... snip ...
}
```

When I set `languageMode` in the `minifyOptions` to `'ES6'`, the errors disappear and the correct JavaScript is served on deployment. You could of course also set `assets.minifyJs` to `false` for the same effect.